# Jest how to cover all branches with global variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jasmine, jestjs

I'm using Jest with React-Native and I stumbled upon a problem.

Tiny snippet of code in App.js component that causes 50:50 branching with coverage:

```
const storeMiddleware = __DEV__ ?
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware
    ) :
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware
    );
```

Test case itself is:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App.js';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('App', () => {
    it('should render correctly', () => {
        const tree = renderer.create(
            <App />
        ).toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
    // TODO: test if app renders correctly when __DEV__ is false
});
```

How should I modify my test to get 100% coverage

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `__DEV__` is a global variable so you can easily change this in the by with

```
global['__DEV__'] = false;
```

Btw. it is not necessary to get 100% coverage and it also makes not much sense to test the settings for your dev eniroment.